# Google App Script - Visualize the survey using Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, data-visualization, google-sheets-api

I used survey to collect data about people opinion. The question is answered using a check-box (Yes/No)

I would like to visualize the results using charts. How can I do that using one column. all the examples that I have seen are related to do graphs between two columns.

For example:

```
col A   
 No      
 Yes     
 Yes
```

Pie chart : 66% YES - 33% NO

I am using this script, but when I run it nothing happend

```
function updateGraph() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  if (charts.length < 1) {
     return;
  }
  var chart = charts[0]; // We operate only on the first graph in this example
  var ranges = chart.getRanges();
  var range = ranges[0]; // ... and we expect it to have only one range
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = dataRange.getNumRows(); // Find the actual number of rows in the sheet
  var rangeA1Notation = "B1:B"+numRows;
  chart = chart.modify().removeRange(range).setOption("title", "Chart over " + rangeA1Notation).addRange(sheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation)).build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart)

}
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function in your spreadsheet like:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"Yes")
```

and the pending

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"No")
```

so you can build the table directly in the spreadsheet:
[image]

[a demo here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p04OEJtGRNsC7ycOYoewtmDzO75XxO1j2Bk791-BI8w/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest finding out how many 'YES's and 'NO's you have first:

```
var numYes = 0;
var numNo = 0;
var rangeYesNo = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
for (i=0; i<rangeYesNo.length; ++i) {
  if (rangeYesNo[i].indexOf('yes') > -1){
    numYes++;}
  if(rangeYesNo[i].indexOf('no') > -1){
    numNo++;}
    }
}
```

and unless you want to try working with building the data structure for the table...
 (see: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)

it might be easier to assign the values to a spot on the spreadsheet and build a table off of that 2x2 segment:

```
sheet.getRange('F1').setValue('Yes');
sheet.getRange('F2').setValue('No');
sheet.getRange('G1').setValue(numYes);
sheet.getRange('G2').setValue(numNo);
var rangeA1Notation = sheet.getRange('F1:G2');
```